# how to return the 3rd elements of a numpy array if a condition is met?

Tags: python, numpy

Helloo, I have a numpy array of (x,y,z) coordinates.

```
coors = [[0,0,7], [1,1,6], [2,2,6], [3,3,6], [4,4,6], [5,5,6]]
```

now I want to get all the 3rd element (z) of each coordinate if the (x,y) is inside a given rectangle

```
rect_mins = 2000,1800   # x_min, y_min
rect_maxs = 2100,1900 # x_max, y_max

coors [coors [:, 0] > 2000 and coors [:, 0] < 2100 and coors [:, 1] > 1800 and coors [:, 1] < 1900]
```

but I get this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

How can I get rid of this error, also what is the most efficient way of doing this operation?

Comment: doesnot work bro, same issue

Comment: Add also parenthesis to the conditions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace *and* (only checks if a statement is true) with **&** (performs bitwise *and* operation) and add Parentheses (to separate each operation)

```
coors [(coors [:, 0] > 2000) & (coors [:, 0] < 2100) & (coors [:, 1] > 1800) & (coors [:, 1] < 1900)]
```

Comment: Perhaps help the OP with an educational aspect and explain *why* `&` is different from `and`.  Just giving an answer is easy, explaining *why* an answer works is much more helpful long term.